# Sending selective data from dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamic table with some data and total counting with JS, when checkbox is ticked row is removed from count.

I need a way to send first ID field and total price to another php page for rows where checkbox is ticked. 
As seen on picture below I need to send vales 8, 10 and 15 with total 1500.
[image]

I have given every checkbox an unique id and value of same id.

```
<table id="price-list">
<tr>
   <td>Some data</td>   
   <td>
       <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" checked="" value="<?php echo $row['rad_id']?>" id="<?php echo $row['rad_id']?>">
   </td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
   <tr  class="totalColumn">
     <td><span> Ukupno:</span></td>
     <td class="total price">0.00 kn</td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Closest that I got is reading whole table with JS, with another script putting it into submit value and passing it into another PHP page.

```
<form action="spec-provjera.php" method="POST">
<input type="button" id="bt" value="Show Table Data" onclick="showTableData()" />
    <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="info" id="info" onclick="myFunction()"/> -->

<script>
    function showTableData() {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
        var myTab = document.getElementById('price-list');

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
        for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {

            // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
            var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

            // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
            for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
                info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
            }
            info.value = info.innerHTML + '<br />';     // ADD A BREAK (TAGG)
        }    
    }
</script>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var info = document.getElementById("info").value;
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",  //type of method
            url  : "spec-provjera.php",  //your page
            data : { info : value.info},// passing the values
            success: function(res){  
                                    //do what you want here...
                    }
        });
    }
    </script>
<button class="w3-btn w3-right w3-deep-orange" type="submit" name="izrada" id="info" onclick="myFunction()"/>KREIRAJ test</button>
</form>
```

This passes all table contains into spec-provjera.php with AJAX but this way is totally messy and posts all rows with check-boxes all set too checked.
Id be happy if I could just filter out cheeked row's.
Can someone suggest a way to do this, keep in mind I'm not very good with JS.

Comment: So this submission happens when the user clicks the button "KREIRAJ test"? Is it necessary to do this using AJAX or you can do a simple submit and refresh the page?

Comment: Correct. Its not necessary this is only way I could think of. Other way would be making all fields from table input fields and create a form out of table? And then filter out checked row's?

Comment: Made it work, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: 
I wrapped whole table as form then made dynamic checkbox unique field and same value "da" like this:

```
 <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" checked="" name="<?php echo $row['rad_id']?>" value="da">
```

Also made an total price field an input with read only like this:

```
 $("tfoot .total.price",tbl).html( '<input type="post" id="total" readonly size="5" value="' + t.toFixed(2) + '" name="total">  kn');
```

Then I'm doing on other PHP page this:

```
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'</br> " ;
}
```

Witch if i uncheck id 14 as seen on first picture gives me:

```
POST parameter '8' has 'da'
POST parameter '10' has 'da'
POST parameter '15' has 'da'
POST parameter 'total' has '1500.00'
```

As seen i have only checked items with total price. Now i can manipulate this as needed in PHP.